# App freeze when I try to move Kinect motor

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect

I am trying to move the motors of my Kinect. It looks pretty simple but it does not work and my app get frozen. I am doing it with Visual Studio 2013 and WPF, this is my code:

Code behind:

```
    private void MotorSliderValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        Angle.Content = (int)MotorSlider.Value;
    }

    private void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        sensor.ElevationAngle = (int)Angle.Content;
    }
```

XAML:

```
<Slider x:Name="MotorSlider" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,10,0,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="262" Maximum="27" SmallChange="1" Minimum="-27" ValueChanged="MotorSliderValueChanged"/>
<Label x:Name="Angle" Content="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="277,10,0,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="43" FontSize="18"/>
<Button Content="Change angle" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="336,10,0,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="102" Click="ButtonClick"/>
```

Any clue why it gets freeze?, it drows an System.InvalidOperationException: This API has returned an exception from an HRESULT: 0x8007000D

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This could be due a consequence of moving the motorized tilt too fast (i.e. setting too fast the `ElevationAngle` property).

According to the official [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.kinectsensor.elevationangle.aspx):

> You must allow at least 20 seconds of rest after 15 consecutive
>   changes. If your application exceeds these limits, the tilt motor may
>   experience a lock period during which attempting to set the elevation
>   angle will result in an **error code**.

This is also confirmed in the "Community Additions" section of the same page:

> If the tilt motor limits are exceeded and the runtime has locked the
>   tilt motor to allow it to rest, attempts to access this property
>   result in throwing an **InvalidOperationException** during the tilt motor
>   lock period.

To solve this issue, I have seen in a sample from Microsoft (I do not remember which sample) that, after changing the `ElevationAngle` property, they explicitly avoid any other changes of this property for a period of 1,35 seconds.

Furthermore, if you try to change the `ElevationAngle` property while Kinect sensor is not running, you can obtain an `InvalidOperationException`. From the same aforementioned page:

> If the ElevationAngle property is accessed while the Kinect sensor is
>   not running (i.e., the Start method has not been called), an
>   InvalidOperationException will be thrown.